# Test apt argument for annotation processor with google compile-testing

Tags: android, gradle, annotation-processing

I am writing annotation processor for my android project and I test it using google compile-testing.

It all works fine except that I am able to test apt plugnin argument to my annotation processor.

My annotation processor has this option that I want to test:

```
@Override
public Set<String> getSupportedOptions() {
    Set<String> options = new HashSet<>();
    options.add("generated_class_suffix");
    return options;
}
```

I do not seem to get how I can pass this options to compile-testing library to test it. I tried `withCompilerOptions` as follows:

```
    assertAbout(javaSource())
            .that(source)
            .withCompilerOptions("saver_suffix")
            .processedWith(new CodegenProcessor())
            .compilesWithoutError()
            .and()
            .generatesSources(generated);
```

but it gives me following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid flag: saver_suffix
```

I am not sure how to pass the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found from the standard `javac` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) how to pass options to annotation processor:

```
-Akey[=value]
```

for example if I want to pass `saver_suffix` as `Saver` I need to pass
    -Asaver_suffix=Saver

so I did:

```
 assertAbout(javaSource())
        .that(source)
        .withCompilerOptions("-Asaver_suffix=Saver")
        .processedWith(new CodegenProcessor())
        .compilesWithoutError()
        .and()
        .generatesSources(generated);
```